# Can I store a "truly private" variable with EIP712?

Tags: cryptography, private, eip712

I've come across [EIP712 utilities in open zepplin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#EIP712). I also found a contract using a draft version [here](https://soliditydeveloper.com/ecrecover). I've modified their contract to something more akin to what I want to do.

I was curious about storing the hash of something onchain and revealing it later. Can my example code below be manipulated in anyway? I.e. retrieve "myParam" before it is revealed by the user?

```
contract MyContract is EIP712 {
    
    mapping(address => bytes32) public digests;    
    mapping (address => uint256) nonces;

    function storeDigest(address owner,
        uint256 myParam,
        uint256 deadline) {
       digests[msg.sender] = _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(
            keccak256("MyFunction(address owner,uint256 myParam,uint256 nonce,uint256 deadline)"),
            owner,
            myParam,
            nonces[owner],
            deadline
        )));
    }

    function revealMyParam(
        bytes memory signature,
        address owner,
        uint256 myParam,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external {
        bytes32 digest = _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(
            keccak256("MyFunction(address owner,uint256 myParam,uint256 nonce,uint256 deadline)"),
            owner,
            myParam,
            nonces[owner],
            deadline
        )));
        
        require(digests[msg.sender] == digest, "different digest")
        address signer = ECDSA.recover(digests[msg.sender], signature);
        require(signer == owner, "MyFunction: invalid signature");
        require(signer != address(0), "ECDSA: invalid signature");

        require(block.timestamp < deadline, "MyFunction: signed transaction expired");
        nonces[owner]++;

        _doSomethingWithMyParamSinceItIsNowRevealed(owner, myParam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, it can be revealed before the reveal. The contract itself is fine, but when your user calls `storeDigest`, the `myParam` property is publicly visible in mempool / later at etherscan. So if an attacker can find the storing tx, he/she can see the plain param value.

Maybe you want to create the hash off-chain and pass it to the contract. Then in the reveal phase, you send the plain values and let the contract compare original hash (from the store phase) with computed hash from the plain values. You can find more about this topic under commit-reveal pattern which is used for on-chain voting.

Comment: Amazing thanks so much! Will read more on that pattern!